# how to break last character only in textarea

Tags: html, jquery, css

How to break last character only in textarea instead of whole words when exceed the max width?
Example below

Sample text

`1. The cash voucher is only valid a physical stores`

My max width able to reach until
`1. The cash voucher is only valid a physical store`
then the 'stores' will auto break to next line as default becomes

`1. The cash voucher is only valid a physical`

`stores`

Expected output

How I do break the 's' to next line only?

`1. The cash voucher is only valid a physical store`

`s and more.....`

Sample code I tried

`<textarea  disabled style="width: 272.12px; overflow: normal ;border: none; outline: none;" id="footerReceipt" ></textarea>`

Comment: Try embedding char(10) + char(13) (carriage return) in the source text

Comment: You don't need the `style=""` because it's not supported in the `<textarea>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the CSS property and value `line-break: anywhere`.

```css
textarea {
  line-break: anywhere
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="48">1. The cash voucher is only valid a physical stores</textarea>
```

Comment: Use the _1. The cash voucher is only valid a physical stores_ with the line-break in the **s** so OP can understand this works. You can put the CSS in the html inside the `<style></style>` tag inside the `<head></head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try `word-break: break-all;`

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) is the documentation for `word-break`.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the columns of the textarea by adding the `cols="50"` inside the textarea tag. You don't need to add the  `style="width: 272.12px; overflow: normal ;border: none; outline: none;" id="footerReceipt"` because it's not supported in textarea (maybe). So it will be like this.

`<textarea disabled rows="10" cols="50">1. The cash voucher is only valid a physical stores</textarea>` If the **s** is not in the new line, try adjusting the number in the `cols=""` until it works.